# Método que reconhece o touch da tela do CELULAR C#

Tags: c#, unity3d

Estou fazendo uma aplicação de realidade aumentada com unity e vuforia. Criei uma classe que faz a bola ficar pulando, agora preciso inserir esse movimento da bola a um touch na tela do celular... Alguém sabe algum método que identifica esse touch?

Comment: creio que isso poderia te ajudar.
https://software.intel.com/pt-br/articles/developing-windows-8-desktop-touch-apps-with-windows-presentation-foundation

Comment: Joana, é sempre ideal você passar o que você tentou fazer pra alcançar o seu objetivo, mesmo sem estar funcionando. Dessa forma a sua pergunta tem mais chances de ser respondida.

Comment: Não coloquei código porque não tinha nenhum Túlio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esse é um exemplo retirado de um [tutorial do site](https://unity3d.com/pt/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/platform-specific/multitouch-input?playlist=17138) do Unity3D.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TouchTest : MonoBehaviour 
{
    void Update () 
    {
        Touch myTouch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        Touch[] myTouches = Input.touches;
        for(int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++)
        {
            //Do something with the touches
        }
    }
}
```

Você pode pegar as coordenadas do toque pela instância de `Touch` que no exemplo é chamada de `myTouch` e ver se colidem com a bola que você tem na tela. Esse `for` do exemplo serve pra você iterar sobre os toques, caso mais de um toque tenha ocorrido ao mesmo tempo.